# Conflict between permission to read gps and phone number

Tags: android

I have a conflict that causes my device to hang when I put both permissions to read gps and phone number in a single activity, but when I test the permissions in two different activities everything works correctly.

Here is part of the permissions in the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Here is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvMensaje;
String mPhoneNumber;
private static final long MIN_TIME = 10000; // 10 segundos Minimo tiempo para updates en Milisegundos
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvMensaje = findViewById(R.id.tvMensaje);

    //*     Permission to Read PhoneNumber
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,READ_PHONE_STATE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)   this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
        return;
    } else {
        requestPermission();
     }

    //*     Permission to Read GPS
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);

    } else {
        iniciarLocalizacion();
    }
}

private void iniciarLocalizacion() {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Localizacion local = new Localizacion();
    local.setMainActivity(this, tvMensaje, mPhoneNumber);
    final boolean gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if(!gpsEnabled) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
        return;
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, local);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, 0, local);

    tvMensaje.setText("Inicializando GPS");
}

private void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_SMS, READ_PHONE_NUMBERS, READ_PHONE_STATE}, 100);
    }
}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 100:
            TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) !=      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
            Log.e( "DEBUG-->", "Nro: " + mPhoneNumber );
            break;

        case 1000:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                iniciarLocalizacion();
                return;
            }
            break;
      }
  }
}
```

[Here the logcat view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGYPg.jpg)

What is my error?

Comment: where you store variable `READ_SMS` etc.? And what is your `Localizacion` class?

Comment: Add `Manifest.permission.` before all permissions in `requestPermission()`

Comment: eto,  el error se presenta al inicio por eso las variables y la clase Localización no lo he incluido en el post por ser mucho código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the array is not empty first:

```
if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    iniciarLocalizacion();
                    return;
                }
                break;
```

You can read more :

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#handle-response